# Trying to build a flow map driver with Geo Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, dynamic-paint

I'm trying to capture an image sequence from file and make Blender understand the directions the white color is going. I've extracted the image sequence from the Dynamic Paint simulation and basically I have to compare the current frame with previous frame and localize the white color upon the mesh surface, and figure out at which direction (X or Y or both) it is going in order to build a flow map - which is basically a normal map that indicates direcion where sth is going. Is it doable?

I imagine I have to use capture or transfer attribute somehow, pick the frame difference between the current and the previous frame and see where the white color has gone, but I'm too stupid to build it alone. Can somebody help me?

Flow map in a nutshell:
[image]

Comment: This sound like a raster based problem. (Dynamic Paint can be an image sequence.) Why do you want to use geometry nodes instead of the compositor?

Comment: Hi! It's because I want to compose a texture upon the trail, say a noise or musgrave for example, so it would follow the flow map path.

Comment: Before some smart user here figures out how to do that, you could simply prerender the sequence with the compositor, then load it into geo nodes as an image sequence.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking, but I want Blender to understande left and right and draw the different directions that the dynamic brush went on, in order to build a flow map.